# split a string list to different fields in python

Tags: python, string, split

Does anyone know how to change a string list such as `['A:a:1','B:b:2]`
to 3 fields and print like

```
capital: A  lower: a number: 2
capital: B  lower: b number: 3
```

by simply using split()

Comment: Could you represent your output in list? and let us know what have you tried?

Comment: Please close the quot in second item: `['A:a:1','B:b:2']` Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
for k in l:
    i=k.split(':')
    print('capital: ', i[0],' lower: ', i[1],' number: ', i[2])
```

Comment: I tried a couple of ways and it gives me error that 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I just tested it again and it works fine on my pc
Did you try it exactly as it is with exactly the same data (by the way your data need a closing paranthesis for second item `['A:a:1','B:b:2']`)

Comment: Probably there are some elements without length of 3. You can apply some conditions based on the length of the elements while printing, to avoid error

Comment: thanks for your help. Do you have any idea that how I can compare i[2]? such as find the smaller number

Comment: You mean in your entire list? You could do this: `min([i[2] for i in your_list])`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
items = ['A:a:1','B:b:2']

for item in items:
   capital_text, lower_text, number_text = item.split(':')
   print('capital:', capital_text, 'lower:', lower_text, 'number:', number_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for string in "A:a:1", "B:b:2":
    print("capital: {} lower: {} number: {}".format(*string.split(":")))
```

Output:

```
capital: A lower: a number: 1
capital: B lower: b number: 2
>>>
```